# in TFS, how to query items by project name?

Tags: tfs, tfs-query

I have a team foundation server and on it there are two projects, named GD and DS.

Now I'd like to create a query which list all the unfinished job of one project, either GD or DS.

The current filter is:
    Team Project = @Project
I don't know what @Project means but I found the result lists all items from 2 project.
I changed like 
    Team Project = GD
but it doesn't work.

So how should I use the filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Project` means the currently selected team project in "Team Explorer". You can put in the name of your Team Project in place of `@Project` and the query will restrict the results to Work Items under that Team Project.

If you are not getting the results you expect, try removing the criteria (even the Team Project filter) and including `Team Project` as a column in your results.

Comment: Thanks, I tested and just found that the result is corret (only shows the items from current project) in Team Explorer, but it's incorrect on the web page. Very strange.

Comment: Oh, it's my fault! I forgot to group the clauses.